# Generate NSString from all the NSStrings in an NSArray

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, nsstring, nsarray

I have an `NSArray` which holds one or more strings. If there's more than one, I want to loop through the array and concatenate the strings to combine all the values.

My final `NSString` should look like `@"food|cafe|restaurant"`. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 5):

```
NSString *finalString = [array componentsJoinedByString:@"|"];
```

Comment: This is my code: NSString *types = [[myArray valueForKey:@"types"] componentsJoinedByString:@"|"];
 NSLog(@"types string  %@", types);                                                         This is the result of log file.                                                                       types string (
    "electronics_store",
    store,
    "movie_rental",
    establishment
)

Comment: update I put a log on myArray and the log is same as log of string. How do I remove quotes from NSArray?